# how to uploading image on pi casa through iPhone sdk

Tags: iphone

In my project i want to take image from my iPhone camera and upload it on Facebook, twitter and pi-casa. Facebook and twitter uploading portion is done but not with pi-casa. 
so can any one help me how to upload images on pi-casa through iPhone sdk. if possible give me some source code or demo to make problem easy.

Thanks & regards,
Priyanka.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think the following link is helpful.
  http://googlemac.blogspot.com/2007/06/picasa-web-albums-meets-google-data.html